# window.load works in chrome but not in ff and ie

Tags: jquery

following function is not working in ff and ie when I call it on windows.load event

```
$(window).load(function() { $("html").replaceText(/\[.*\]/,""); }
```

but it works fine in chrome and if I call it on document.ready event and it works vice versa

**Function**

```
$.fn.replaceText = function(search, replace, text_only) {  
  return this.each(function(){  
    var v1, v2, rem = [];
    $(this).find("*").andSelf().contents().each(function(){
        if(this.nodeType === 3) {
            v1 = this.nodeValue;
            v2 = v1.replace(search, replace);
            if(v1!=v2) {
                if(!text_only && /<.*>/.test(v2)) {  
                    $(this).before( v2 );  
                    rem.push(this);  
                }
                else this.nodeValue = v2;  
            }
        }
    });
    if(rem.length) $(rem).remove();
 });
};
```

Comment: That function is really _expensive_, poor browser.

Comment: Do you get any errors? What do you see if you put `console.log($("html"));` in the function?

Comment: it doesn't print any error in console

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(window).ready` rather than `$(window).load`

`load` is more useful on something like an image being done. I wouldn't use it for the `document` or `window`.

If that's not the answer let me know why you were trying `load`.